# How to move a module from one CVS repository to another?

Tags: repository, cvs, transfer

Is it possible to move a module from one CVS repository to another not losing the history (including the deleted files)?

I have two CVS repositories and I want to move a module (a top-level sub-directory of the CVS root direcory) from one to the other.

Can I simply move the module directory, or is there something else to do? It seems that CVSROOT directory in the repository's directory does contain some references to the modules.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to move (or copy) the top level module directory from one repository to another. The history of the module is self-contained.

If you want to maintain any additional behaviour (eg. pre-commit hooks) then you will have to copy the references to the module in the CVSROOT module.